# Cordova / Quasar Framework - Problem with file permissions

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, quasar-framework

i've been having problems to download a file to my "Downloads" folder with my app.

I've put on my config.xml and checked on AndroidManifest.xml and both of them have the explicit permissions:

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NETWORK_ACCESS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I'm using **cordova-plugin-android-permissions** to check them on the fly, and they are there too.
Using only **cordova-plugin-file** + XMLHttpRequest as recomended on docs it did not throw any erros, but the file is not there when downloaded.
When I go back to use the **cordova-plugin-file-transfer** it gave me the following response:

```js
{
  body: null
  code: 1
  exception: "/storage/emulated/0/download/test.mp3 (Permission denied)"
  http_status: 200
  source: "http://192.168.0.10/test.mp3"
  target: "file:///storage/emulated/0/download/test.mp3"
}
```

My current code is the following:

```js
downloadFile(){
  var app = this;
  var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;
  permissions.checkPermission([permissions.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,permissions.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE],
    /* Permission ok ok*/
    function(){
      let downloadUrl = "http://192.168.0.10/test.mp3";
      let name = "test.mp3"
      let filePath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + 'download/' + name
      let fileTransfer = new window.FileTransfer()
      let uri = encodeURI(decodeURIComponent(downloadUrl))

  // Downloading the file
  fileTransfer.download(uri, filePath,
    function (entry) {
      console.log('Successfully downloaded file, full path is ' + entry.fullPath)
      console.log(entry)
    },
    function (error) {
      console.log('error',error)
    },
    false
    )
  },

/* Asks for Permission */
function(errorLoad){
    permissions.requestPermissions([permissions.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,permissions.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE],
  /* Permission Granted */ 
  function(){app.requestSystem()}, 

  /* Permissão Denied */
  function(errorLoad){
    console.error(errorLoad)
  });
  });     

}
```

I would appreciate any help! What I'm missing?

Comment: did you solve it?